# Test a string for a substring

Tags: python, string

Is there an easy way to test a Python string "xxxxABCDyyyy" to see if "ABCD" is contained within it?

Answer (score 225, accepted):

```
if "ABCD" in "xxxxABCDyyyy":
    # whatever
```

Comment: This works here, but may not give the expected results if you are testing against a non-string.  E.g. if testing against a list of strings (perhaps with `if "ABCD" in ["xxxxabcdyyyy"]`), this can fail silently.

Comment: @GreenMatt if you know it's a list just say `if 'ABCD' in list[0]`.

Answer (score 36):

There are several other ways, besides using the `in` operator (easiest):

> `index()`

```
>>> try:
...   "xxxxABCDyyyy".index("test")
... except ValueError:
...   print "not found"
... else:
...   print "found"
...
not found
```

> `find()`

```
>>> if "xxxxABCDyyyy".find("ABCD") != -1:
...   print "found"
...
found
```

> `re`

```
>>> import re
>>> if re.search("ABCD" , "xxxxABCDyyyy"):
...  print "found"
...
found
```

Comment: The last one requires and `re.escape` call in the general case though.