# Comparing efficiency of two substring searching methods in Python

Tags: python

After searching the topic of substring searching in python ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361253/python-how-to-find-a-substring-in-another-string), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473014/test-a-string-for-a-substring)) I found two obvious solutions

```
str1 = 'Hi there'
str2 = 'Good bye'
# 1
if str1.find('Hi') != -1: 
    print 'Success!'
# 2
if 'Good' in str2:
    print 'Success'
```

- Is there a difference in the generated code by those two or the second one is just syntactic sugar ?
- Is one or the other more efficient?
- Is there a third option

Comment: in terms of complexity they are both `O(n)` use the one that makes sense for a given senario ... if you want to get an index use `find` ... if you want to test membership use `in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* check what the bytecode looks like for those conditions:

```
In [1]: import dis

In [2]: dis.dis(lambda: 'Hi' in x)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Hi') 
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x) 
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in) 
              9 RETURN_VALUE         

In [3]: dis.dis(lambda: x.find('Hi') != -1)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (x) 
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (find) 
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Hi') 
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair) 
             12 LOAD_CONST               3 (-1) 
             15 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=) 
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see the `find` versions does a lot more, in particular it is doing an attribute lookup which is not needed for the `in` operator.

I must also say that `in` makes it more explicit that you are checking for the presence of a substring and not of its position, and thus it is more readable.

In terms of speed they should be perfectly equal for any reasonable size of strings. Only for the smallest strings the attribute lookup has a significant impact, but in that case the condition is checked very fast anyway.

The third option would be to use `index` and catch the exception:

```
try:
    string.index(substring)
except IndexError:
    # not found
else:
    # found
```

Although this cannot be expressed as a simple *expression*.

Answer (score 0):

The second isn't just syntactic sugar for the first. `str.find` is just a method call, whereas `a in b` calls `a.__contains__(b)`. I don't think there are any differences in speed.

I would recommend the second, as it is more Pythonic:

It is more readable.
It uses duck typing. The string could be replaced by a different iterable, and it would still work.