# Compare 2 files in python and print non-matching text

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two files:

```
Resp.txt:
vrf XXX
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  import route-target
   123:45
   212:43
  !
  export route-policy ABCDE
  export route-target
   9:43
  !
  maximum prefix 12 34
  spanning tree enable
  bandwidth 10
 !
!
```

and sample.txt

```
vrf
address-family ipv4 unicast
import route-target
export route-target
maximum prefix
```

I want to match `resp.txt` and `sample.txt` such that if contents of sample are not present in resp, I get those lines of text. The output should be like:

```
spanning tree enable
bandwidth 10
```

I am using :

```
t2=open('sample.txt','r')
abc=open('resp.txt','r')
for x in t2:
  for line in abc:

         if x.strip() in line.strip():
          print 'yes'
         else:
          print line
```

But it's matching every line in both the text files and hence, not showing the correct result.

Comment: What is `resp`? Note you can only iterate over a file handle once, so only the first iteration of your loop over `t2` will actually do anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe resp is a file against which I have to match. Is there any alternate way of achieving my output?

Comment: strip() is empty so it's useless, do you want to skip whitespaces? then use strip(' ')

Comment: @Ale, I am able to match but not getting the desired output.

Comment: @jonrsharpe resp.txt is my file and I am reading it using resp[1].

Comment: @alisha it's strange if they match but the output is wrong, try some of this comparisons: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5473150/7094875

Comment: @alisha resp[1] is gramatically a list because you are using an index '[1]', so maybe the problem is in there

Comment: Your indentation is still completely wrong. People should be able to copy and paste this and replicate the issue. Did you *try* using readlines?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Tried, still not getting.

Comment: @Ale - [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) without arguments removes whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

So the simplest solution to get all the strings not in `sample.txt` is to use set difference:

```
file_1 = set()
file_2 = set()

with open('Resp.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        file_1.add(line.strip())

with open('Sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        file_2.add(line.strip())

print(file_1 - file_2)
```

Which returns:

```
{'export route-policy ABCDE', 'vrf XXX', 'spanning tree enable', '!', '212:43', 'bandwidth 10', 'maximum prefix 12 34', '9:43', '123:45'}
```

However, this doesn't include certain rules applied to `Resp.txt`, for example:

- If line is "maximum prefix" ignore the numbers.

These rules can be applied while reading `Resp.txt`:

```
import re

file_1 = set()
file_2 = set()

with open('Resp.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == "!":
            continue
        elif re.match( r'\d+:\d+', line): # Matches times.
            continue
        elif line.startswith("vrf"):
            line = "vrf"
        elif line.startswith("maximum prefix"):
            line = "maximum prefix"
        file_1.add(line)

with open('Sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        file_2.add(line.strip())

print(file_1) - file_2)
```

Which returns:

```
{'export route-policy ABCDE', 'bandwidth 10', 'spanning tree enable'}
```

Which is correct because `sample.txt` does not contain `route-policy`.

These rules could be made more robust, but they should be illustrative enough.

Keep in mind `set` will only find unique differences, and not all (say you have multiple `'spanning tree enable'` lines and would like to know how many times these are seen. In that case, you could do something more in line with your original code:

```
import re

file_1 = []
file_2 = []

with open('Resp.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == "!":
            continue
        elif re.match( r'\d+:\d+', line):
            continue
        elif line.startswith("vrf"):
            line = "vrf"
        elif line.startswith("maximum prefix"):
            line = "maximum prefix"
        file_1.append(line)

with open('Sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        file_2.append(line.strip())

diff = []

for line in file_1:
    if line not in file_2:
        diff.append(line)

print(diff)
```

Result:

```
['export route-policy ABCDE', 'spanning tree enable', 'bandwidth 10']
```

While this method is slower (although you probably won't notice), it can find duplicate lines and maintains the order of the lines found.